# How do I access an airflow rendered template downstream?

Tags: python, airflow

Airflow version: 1.10.12

I'm having trouble passing a rendered template object for use downstream. I'm trying to grab two config variables from the Airflow conf.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

from datetime import datetime


with DAG(
    dag_id="example_trigger_target_dag",
    default_args={"owner": "airflow"},
    start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 24),
    schedule_interval='@once',
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task",
        bash_command='echo "{{ conf.test }}:{{ conf.tag }}"',
        xcom_push=True
    )
```

Basically what it passes to xcom is just `:` without the variables present.  The full rendered string does show up however in the `rendered` tab.  Am I missing something?

Edit: the variables exist in the conf, I just replaced them with `test` and `tag` for security reasons.

Comment: Can you test `bash_command='echo "{{ dag_run.conf["test"] }}:{{ dag_run.conf["tag"] }}"',`?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this code (I'm using Airflow 2.1.0) and got that result.

```
BashOperator(task_id='test_task',
                     bash_command='echo " VARS: {{ conf.email.email_backend '
                                  '}}:{{ conf.core.executor }}"',
                     do_xcom_push=True)
```

[image: xcom]